# Unable to figure out regex bash or sed or awk

Tags: regex

I wanted to split the following `jdk-1.6.0_30-fcs.x86_64` to just `jdk-1.6.0_30`. I tried the following `sed 's/\([a-z][^fcs]*\).*/\1/'`but I end up with `jdk-1.6.0_30-`. I think am approaching it the wrong way, is there a way to start from the end of the word and traverse backwards till I encounter `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can anchor the pattern to the end of the string with `$`. Then you just need to make sure that the characters you repeat may not include hyphens:

```
echo jdk-1.6.0_30-fcs.x86_64 | sed 's/-[^-]*$//'
```

This will match from a `-` to the end of the string, but all characters in between must be different from `-` (so that it does not match for the first hyphen already).

A slightly more detailed explanation. The engine tries to match the literal `-` first. That will first work at the first `-` in the string (obviously). Then `[^-]*` matches as many non-`-` characters as possible, so it will consume `1.6.0_30` (because the next character is in fact a hyphen). Now the engine will try to match `$`, but that does not work because we are not at the end of the string. Some backtracking occurs, but we can ignore that here. In the end the engine will abandon matching the first `-` and continue through the string. Then the engine will match the literal `-` with the second `-`. Now `[^-]*` will consume `fcs.x86_64`. Now we are actually at the end of the string and `$` will match, so the full match (which will be removed is) `-fcs.x86_64`.

Comment: Still a little confused, so the first `-` includes the `-` then the `[]` excludes the `-` and anything after that? So if there were 3 `-` then this would print everything to the first 2?

Comment: @noMAD No. `-` matches a hyphen. `[^-]` matches non-hyphen-character. `*` requires zero or more of those. and `$` matches the end of the string. this can only match a string from the last `-` to the end of the string. otherwise there would be another `-` between the matched one and the end of the string, so `[^-]*` could not reach the end of the string and `$` would not match. does that make any sense?

Comment: @noMAD I added a detailed explanation to the answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
echo 'jdk-1.6.0_30-fcs.x86_64' | sed 's/-fcs.*//'
```

If using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) or [ash](/questions/tagged/ash), you can do :

```
var=jdk-1.6.0_30-fcs.x86_64
echo ${var%%-fcs*}
jdk-1.6.0_30
```

Later solution use *parameter expansion*, tested on Linux and Minix3

Comment: This requires the `-` to be followed by `fcs` though.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `cut` >>

```
echo 'jdk-1.6.0_30-fcs.x86_64' | cut -d- -f-2
```